# ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s) on simple insert

Tags: mysql

I keep getting that error

> ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s).

I have table `Deck` which has `DeckId, PlayerId, CardId` (player and card are foreign keys from table `Collection`). And all three are primary key for that table.
I am trying to do simple Insert on Deck.

```
INSERT INTO Deck (DeckId, PlayerId, CardId) 
VALUES (1, 1, 1);
```

And I keep getting that error. I modeled database with MySql workbench. `Deck` is dependent on `Collection`, it has identifying 1:m relationship. I don't know if that may be causing problems.

Here is paste for create [schema](http://pastebin.com/Y6yzWYjX), [triggers](http://pastebin.com/kSVcNjsX). Names are not in English. It is model of DB for card game Hearthstone, dunno if I should use that name, but it is for a school project, I guess professor won't mind.

Comment: Your insert query looks ok to me.

Comment: Does the Deck table have a trigger defined on insert?

Comment: Are you sure error is coming in this statement only?

Comment: Maybe if you show us the actual schema

Comment: Aded create schema in edit. I guess I should also add triggers and insert statements? Silly me.

Answer (score 0):

I found what the mistake was.

It was not problem in insert statement but in create trigger statement. It returned 2 rows instead of 1. 
Thank you all.